# Reading integer from text file, doing maths, writing the result back fails

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to make a loop by creating a `.txt` file and removing numbers from it constantly until the variable in the `.txt` file is `0`.
This is how far I got:

```
@echo off
set /p a=<Name.txt
set /a c=%a%-1
echo %c%> Name.txt
echo %a%
echo %c%
PAUSE
```

Inside the text file I input a number, for example `8`.
What it is meant to do is take that number and subtract `1` from it then it is meant to memorise it and then overwrite the text file again with a resut of `8 - 1` which is `7`.
So in the text file called `Name.txt` I would expect to see `7` but what I see is a blank line. Please help me out with this loop. I was trying to make an invisible code window which would appear and post a message out of nowhere.

Comment: Oh I think I have it written wrong I posted in a hurry let me re post here is the code.

Comment: Any ideas people?

Comment: `echo %c%>Name.txt` is a bad idea. Better use `>Name.txt echo %c%`. [Reason](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: How is "Notepad", that appears both in the title and tags of this question, even remotely related? I suggest an edit to eliminate it...

Comment: I cannot see any loop structure in your code, so where is it meant to be?

Answer (score 3):

In place of

```
echo %c%> Name.txt
```

use

```
>Name.txt echo %c%
```

Numerics directly before redirectors may cause problems

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confused by your code. You are storing the content of name.txt in the variable %a% (`set /p a=<Name.txt`). Then you are echoing `%c%` into your text file. How is this supposed to work? `%c%` is never set in your code. You are also missing the complete part where you are reducing the number by one. Further, you don't have to delete the file and create it again. Simply replace >> with > to overwrite the complete content of the file.

However, this code should do what you need:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:LOOP
SET /P a=<name.txt
SET /a a=!a!-1
ECHO !a!>name.txt
PAUSE
IF NOT !a!==0 GOTO LOOP
```

Comment: %a%-1 here is the part

Comment: What do you mean by "%a%-1 here is the part"? This line is not in the code you've posted.

Comment: Still even If I do as you say it gives me a blank space

Comment: Let's make sure that I've understood the question. You have a text file containing a number. Let's say it's 5. You want a loop which will read the number, reduce it by one, write the new number into the text file and redo the loop until the number is 0. If this is the case, my code will do exactly this. At the end there will be a 0 in your text file and the loop will stop.

Comment: Yes correct I just did not get too far. I am testing this bit first and it gives me a blank space. Also I edited the code so read it again

Comment: OK, now the subtraction is there :) Now what exactly is giving you a white space? Is this the whole code? If it's not and there is any kind of loop in there, you will have to add `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and replace % with !.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is the line `echo %c%> Name.txt` in case `%c` holds a single decimal digit, because such is interpreted as [redirection handle](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) together with the `>` symbol. Your code should work with respect to that as long as `%c%` holds a number consisting of more than one digits.

To solve this problem, there are the following options:

1. Move the redirection part to the front:

   ```
   > Name.txt echo %c%
   ```

   This is the most reliable solution.
2. Put the redirected command in between parentheses:

   ```
   (echo %c%) > Name.txt
   ```
3. Insert a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the `>` symbol:

   ```
   echo %c% > Name.txt
   ```

   Note that the added space becomes part of the output.